# Reduce is giving error while for loop is working fine

Tags: python, loops, functional-programming, python-unicode

I have a list contents which contains lxml.etree._ElementStringResult and lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult

```
for x in contents:
        final_content += (x.encode('utf-8')) + '\n'
```

and

```
final_content = reduce(lambda a, x: a+x.encode('utf-8') + '\n', contents)
```

The first code is running fine while the second code is raising a unicode decode error.

```
<ipython-input-129-17a363dfff6c> in <lambda>(a, x)
----> 1 final_content = reduce(lambda a, x: a+x.encode('utf-8') + '\n', contents)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position
37: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Edit:

The reduce is failing because the first element is not encoded.

When i changed the code to

```
final_content = contents[0]
for x in range(1,len(contents)):
     final_content += contents[x].encode('utf-8')
```

It is raising the same error like the reduce block above.

Comment: off topic:  `final_content = u'\n'.join( [x.encode('utf-8') for x in contents]  )`

Comment: @bhargav This question is about the problems with reduce and not encoding.

Comment: @danihp That comment was meant for the mods who closed the question as duplicate.

Comment: ok man, I posted my answer inside @hjpotter92 answer. I hope he don't be sad.

Comment: @danihp Yes, thanks i figured it out and replaced the code with 
`reduce(lambda a, x: a+x.encode('utf-8') + '\n', contents, contents[0].encode('utf-8'))`
Should have edited the question after figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because your `\n` is not utf-8 encoded. Simply setting to be a unicode string should fix the issue:

```
final_content = reduce(lambda a, x: a + x.encode('utf-8') + u'\n', contents)
```

**Sorry 'answer owner' about edit here your question without your permission, but question is closed and I can't post the right answer. Be free to remove this content:**

Op, you are assuming that both codes are the same behaviour, but is not! Because on first map iteration you are concatenating first and second element without the `\n`. And you are doing it encoding second element but without encoding first one. The right translation from your classical `for` loop to your `reduce` approach is:

```
final_content = reduce(lambda a, x: 
                           a+x.encode('utf-8') + u'\n', 
                       contents, 
                       u'\n')    # <----- initializer
```

Notice that without initializer you are doing:

```
contents[0] + contents[1].encode('utf-8')
```

and this is what raises the error!

Comment: It is still raising the same error.

Comment: updated after ^^ comment.